# Drag out from Adobe Air Desktop Application

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, air, adobe

I have some ByteArray in my app. User can be able to drag out icon to folder and file with content of my ByteArray should be created there. 
I spend a lot of time but can't find any way to get folder where user dragged icon from application. Now i only can able to pass ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT with exist file to copy it to directory where user dragged icon, but i can't handle event when copying is done. So in fact i can't be sure copying finished, because i don't know destination folder...
Please help.

Comment: Sorry, impossible to help without any code.

Comment: I need to know destination where user drag out. (here is very basic project https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByXxzqRIxDExMzh0NENGUVVBUXM/view?usp=sharing) so i can only pass command, like copy file or etc. But i don't know how to get path to directory where user drag out.